# Kafka Streams PAPI: AbstractProcessor objects creation behaviour

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams topology that contains an AbstractProcessor(actually, two). 
In one of them, I'm using the `Punctuation API` with `WALL_CLOCK_TIME` to schedule a refresh of some reference data that is needed for processing. 
I do it on start of the task, and then schedule every so often (let's say 1h). 
`num.stream.threads` is configured to 2.

E.g. I have some code like this:

```
def loadReferenceData() = {
      logger.info("Loading All Reference Data...")
      // atomically (re)load some data
}

override def init(context: ProcessorContext) = {
      super.init(context)
      logger.info("Loading reference data initially...")
      loadReferenceData()

      context.schedule(1000 * reloadDataSeconds, PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, (timestamp) => {
        loadReferenceData()
        context.commit(); // Unsure if necessary
      });
}
```

Without incoming records, in logs of a single instance on running application, I can see these logs for the init:

```
    [2019-06-11 08:54:19,518] INFO Loading All Reference Data... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
    [2019-06-11 08:53:31,080] INFO Loading All Reference Data... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
    [2019-06-11 08:53:29,713] INFO Loading All Reference Data... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
    [2019-06-11 08:53:29,682] INFO Loading All Reference Data... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
    [2019-06-11 07:54:20,855] INFO Loading All Reference Data... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
    [2019-06-11 07:54:19,714] INFO Loading All Reference Data... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
    [2019-06-11 07:54:19,516] INFO Loading All Reference Data... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
    [2019-06-11 07:53:31,036] INFO Loading All Reference Data... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
    [2019-06-11 07:53:29,668] INFO Loading All Reference Data... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
    [2019-06-11 07:53:29,653] INFO Loading All Reference Data... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
    [2019-06-11 06:54:20,845] INFO Loading All Reference Data... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
    [2019-06-11 06:54:19,726] INFO Loading All Reference Data... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
```

So it seems there are a number of logs for entering `loadReferenceData`, every hour. I expected to see 2 entries per hour only (2 threads), but there are more (usually 6).

In the logs I have only seen the creation of my processor 6 times at the beginning of the application creation:

```
[2019-06-10 16:54:19,849] INFO Loading reference data initially... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
[2019-06-10 16:54:18,231] INFO Loading reference data initially... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
[2019-06-10 16:54:17,874] INFO Loading reference data initially... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
[2019-06-10 16:53:29,675] INFO Loading reference data initially... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
[2019-06-10 16:53:27,132] INFO Loading reference data initially... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
[2019-06-10 16:53:24,923] INFO Loading reference data initially... (com.divvit.dp.streams.applications.StreamProcessor)
```

So this makes sense: a Processor is created once, and once an hour it will update.

But when I put more load into my application, I can see the creation of new Processor objects quite often.

- Under which circumstances will Kafka Streams create new instances of these Processors?
- How can I know how many processor instances my application instance will create?
- If processors can be being closed/created at Kafka Streams discretion, it looks like for these "external" operations Punctuation API is overkill(or just not designed for that), and a separate periodically updating thread would better do the trick, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka-Streams will create one processor per partition on the input topic, every processor will have its own schedule. (This is actually quite useful if you use state stores as the state will also be partitioned.)

The scheduler is useful if you want to apply regular operations on your internal state. It nicely stops the regular processing and make sure that everything you do during the schedule operations is consistent. If the task at hand has nothing to do with the streaming as such, a separate thread might be as good.

If you choose for a separate thread, make sure to kill it appropriately when the [kafka-streams thread crashes](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-). Otherwise you'll application will hang on the timer thread, but without consuming any kafka messages.

Increasing the number of threads (`num.stream.threads`) means that multiple partitions will be consumed at the same time. It has the same behaviour as starting multiple instances next to each other. See https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#threading-model